# Save / Display of image within asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, image, file-upload

I have been through pretty much every post on this site it seems that deals with image upload & persistence to a sql server database however, something I'm doing is still not right.

The image is either not saving correctly or pulling from the database correctly as while bytes are being written / retrieved the image is not valid. When comparing the size of the image that was uploaded to the original the size is different (larger)?

*Model*:

```
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
public string PhotoMimeType { get; set; }
public string PhotoName { get; set; }
```

*Sql Server*:

```
[PhotoMimeType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PhotoName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Photo] [image] NULL,
```

*Within a controller I have the following to save an image*:

```
public ActionResult Edit(AgentInfo modifiedAgent, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var model = _agentRepository.GetByID(modifiedAgent.AgentID);
        if (TryUpdateModel(model))
        {
            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                int imageLength = postedFile.ContentLength;
                byte[] imgBytes = new byte[imageLength];
                postedFile.InputStream.Read(imgBytes, 0, imageLength);

                model.PhotoMimeType = postedFile.ContentType;
                model.PhotoName = postedFile.FileName;
                model.Photo = imgBytes;
            }
            _agentRepository.Save(model);
            return RedirectToAction("ManageAgents", "Agent");  
        }
    }

    return View("Edit", modifiedAgent);
}
```

*The retrieval*:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{
    var agent = _agentRepository.GetByID(id);
    return File(agent.Photo, agent.PhotoMimeType, agent.PhotoName);
}
```

*The display*:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GetImage", "Agent", new { id = Model.AgentID })' />
```

**EDIT:**

Well after thinking it was a problem with how I was wiring this all together it turned out to be my database mappings.....frick

Fyi, when mapping with fluent-nhibernate and you want to save image bytes, sql data type is varbinary(max) with the following mapping:

```
Map(x => x.Photo).Column("Photo").Length(2147483647).CustomSqlType("varbinary(MAX)");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try rewinding the InputStream just before reading it:

```
postedFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
```

or use a temporary `MemoryStream`:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    postedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    model.Photo = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Darin after going through both options you provided it lead me to deeper digging and I found the problem which was in my fluent-nhibernate mappings